# Adding/modifying unique constraints on a replicated table

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I have an existing table in a replicated environment, I know there are restriction on schema changes that can be done on this table. Can I do the following.

1. Add a unique constrainst on publisher and will it replicate to subscribers?
2. If there is an existing unique constraint on that table, can I modify it on publisher and will modification replicate to subscribers?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I don't think unique constraints are being replicated automatically. we use transaction replication and if column is created, then yes, it's created on subscriber too, but indexes and foreign keys we have to create manually.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your article's so-called schema_option. Take a look at schema_option 0x4000 at BOL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo0483a157-e403-4fdb-b943-23c1b487bef0.aspx

Using option 0x4000 you can decide wether to replicate unique constraints or not. Hope that helps, Fritz